# Could not get unknown property 'manifestOutputDirectory'

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to "make project" with Android Studio, and I'm getting this error:

Execution failed for task ':myApp:processGoogleDebugManifest'.

> Could not get unknown property 'manifestOutputDirectory' for task ':myApp:processGoogleDebugManifest' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest.

Any help please?

EDIT: This error occurred after I updated to gradle v6.5 and plugin v4.1.0. If I revert to gradle v6.1.1 and plugin v4.0.0 the error disappears.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I encountered this same issue today, in my case it was caused by an outdated version of Huawei's AG Connect plugin. I was using `com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301`, but when I updated it to `com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300` the issue was fixed.

**See Latest Huawei's AG Connect plugin here:** [https://developer.huawei.com/latest/plugin/agconnect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-android-0000001058210705) ...Just scroll, you'll find it there haha!

But if Huawei's plugin is not the problem you are having, you can debug the issue by running `gradle` with `--stacktrace` option to see where the issue originates from. In Android Studio you can add command line options for `gradle` in `Settings`/`Build, Execution, Deployment`/`Compiler`/`Command-line options`.

Comment: That's exactly the issue :) I was using com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300. Updating to 1.4.1.300 fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: Same issue here, Thanks!

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks for sharing and saving us some time!

Comment: Updating to 1.4.2.300 fixed it

Comment: `classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301'` has worked too

Comment: Latest version is com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.1.300

Comment: Huawei just allow to have error. Because I still get get manifestOutputDirectory error but app is building fine ;)

Comment: check it out the latest version https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-get-started-android-0000001058210705

Answer (score 12):

This solved my same problem:

In the project level build.gradle, replace this:

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.1.300'
```

with this:

```
classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'
```

Reference: https://github.com/Tencent/tinker/issues/1471#issuecomment-710777366

Answer (score 4):

I write it here because this solution saved my day :

We can fix this by simply replacing references to

```
manifestOutputDirectory
```

by

```
multiApkManifestOutputDirectory
enter code here
```

in your gradle tasks

For example :

> ```
> android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>     variant.outputs.all { output ->
>         output.processManifest.doLast { task ->
>             def outputDir = multiApkManifestOutputDirectory.asFile.get()
>             String manifestMergerpath = "$outputDir/AndroidManifest.xml"
>             writeManifest(manifestMergerpath, placeholders)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: hi where to replace it ?

Comment: thumb up dude you saved my day too

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bugsnag, replace the following line

```
classpath 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:4.+'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:5.+'
```

For further detail, see this issue: [Fails with AGP 4.1.0-alpha04](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin/issues/194) and [this comment](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin/issues/194#issuecomment-668162014).

Comment: this helped me figure out why I couldn't get bugsnag working on the latest version of React Native 64.2. thx!

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
android.applicationVariants.all {
    outputs.all {
        processManifestProvider.configure {
            val multiApkManifestOutputDirectory = (this as ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest)
                .multiApkManifestOutputDirectory // 
            doLast {
                multiApkManifestOutputDirectory.get()
                    .asFile
                    .walkTopDown()
                    .forEach { 
                        
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```