# unknown property ‘manifestOutputDirectory’

Tags: android, gradle

I had to integrate a library into my app and the library had its gradle version as 4.0.0, while my app had 3.2.2 (or something). So it bumped into the `queries` tag in the library (in its Manifest) that it wouldn’t recognize. Therefore I have updated the gradle version in my app to be the same as the library, at 4.0.0 (now I put it as 4.1.0, the latest).

The problem is that I bump into the following error:

`Execution failed for task ‘:app:processCanaryDebugManifest’.

`Could not get unknown property ‘manifestOutputDirectory’ for task ‘:app:processCanaryDebugManifest’ of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest.`

This is based on this warning:

`API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.`

I haven’t been able to make any progress on this. I have ran the gradlew command with --stacktrace but all I get are errors from gradle, nothing specific. Do you know of any way to make this work? The only things I've found so far are issues with a Huawei thing, but it's not the case for me. Thanks!

PS. I'm not sure what additional info would be useful in this circumstance.

EDIT: I've downgraded to gradle 3.3.3 and commented out my new library dependecies, and now it says:

`Execution failed for task ':app:processCanaryDebugManifest'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$FixedDirectory, C:\build\myapp\app))))\AndroidManifest.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`

Comment: Some more info which might help: The gradle stacktrace anyways, your build.gradle files and after upgrading gradle, are you still adding the library or did you try without? In any case, try without the library and if it only happens with the library, tell us which library it is

Comment: Perhaps this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64390789/2232127

Comment: I have read that already. I have also run `gradlew assembleQa -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` like it recommends, you end up with a huge pile of groovy classes being called and the same error. The crash occurs even if I comment out the new library dependencies, supposedly because I increased the gradle version for my project `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'`

Comment: clear your gradle caches and show us your build.gradle files

Comment: Can't, it has a bunch of sensitive data (plus, it's huge).

Comment: Something is definitely broken right now, clear all caches AS / gradle, revert your changes and if it doesn't work it's a separate issue. I don't think we can help you further without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I know, I was hoping someone bumped into this error in the past and knows what's up, especially this: java.io.FileNotFoundException: property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, transform(property(interface org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout$FixedDirectory, C:\build\myapp\app))))\AndroidManifest.xml (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)`. As you can see, it points incorrectly in "C:\build" instead of the "C:\AndroidStudioProjects...". If only I could find where this is declared...

Comment: I don't beleive that's declared anywhere. My intuition is some broken cache, which also a sudden downgrade of gradle might provoke. If your code is in the previous "unbroken" state, it would also point to cache issues. Gradle has caches in `$userdir/.gradle/caches` and `$projectdir/build`and `$projectdir/$module/build`

Comment: Or perhaps you're running gradlew from cmd and your currect directory is incorrect? It's hard to say from the provided info