# Why am I getting 'manifestOutputDirectory' error after android studio update?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

My android studio has just updated and after that my app is not able to compile anymore. It shows this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Could not get unknown property 'manifestOutputDirectory' for task ':app:processDebugManifest' of type
> com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest.

Android studio: 4.1

Android gradle plugin version: 4.1.0

Gradle: 6.6.1

Comment: It was an outdated Huawei's AG Connect plugin. Solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64390789/1363087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an outdated Huawei's AG Connect plugin. Solution here: [stackoverflow.com/a/64390789/1363087](http://stackoverflow.com/a/64390789/1363087)